# how I deploy rest service extension using gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, marklogic

Rest service : http://host:8000/v1/config/resources/removeCollection?put:database=string&put:uris=string*

I want to deploy this [REST service extension](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/config/resources/%5Bname%5D) in MarkLogic using gradle. How can I deploy this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using `ml-gradle`, you can add your implemented interface to `marklogic\src\main\ml-modules\services` and deploy using the `mlLoadModules` task. The `mlCreateResource` task as part of the scaffolding would also add metadata in `marklogic\src\main\ml-modules\services\metadata`.

Comment: In 'src\main\ml-modules\root\services',I kept my rest extension service example.xqy and In gradle.properties I kept resourceName=example
resourceType=xqy
But when I run 

task deploy(dependsOn: [
    mlDeleteModuleTimestampsFile, mlDeploy, mlLoadSchemas, applyParameters, loadCpfModules,mlCreateResource, initSchemas]) {}
 
It is creating example.xqy and metadata in this location  'src\main\ml-modules\services' and also the example.xqy contains default structure that contains all the methods 
and  also the service extension example.xqy not created in modules database

Comment: Using gradle version : id 'com.marklogic.ml-gradle' version '3.17.0'

Comment: how can I pass parameter ?put:database=string&put:uris=string*  along with rest extension service

Comment: I am almost certain you can provide metadata in a subfolder called metadata, with files called {extension}.xml, so src/main/ml-modules/services/example.xqy (no root/!), and src/main/ml-modules/services/metadata/example.xml. The metadata contains something as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41860941/918496

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at [`ml-gradle`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle#readme). You can easily hook it up in gradle by adding a few lines, most importantly being:

```
plugins { id "com.marklogic.ml-gradle" version "4.0.4" }
```

As described in the readme, you can optionally follow that with invoking the `mlNewProject` task, which will provide you with a useful scaffold structure for a typical ml-gradle project.

ML-gradle gives you access to all kinds of tasks, including one called `mlLoadModules` to deploy source, and rest extensions. There is also a built-in task for removing collections in any database, called `mlDeleteCollections`. You can look at the [Task-reference](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference) to get a glimpse of all the tasks, or just run `gradle tasks`.

HTH!

Comment: Actually ,I added the name (Remove collection) for just an example.Please Read the above comments

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways of plugin gradle to invoke REST API:

> Method One:
> If you don’t have any `Project` just yet,

1. create a `gradle.properties` file in which you define four parameters: `host`, `mlUsername`, `mlPassword`, `RestPort`
2. create a `build.gradle` file in the same folder:

```
plugins { 
    id "com.marklogic.ml-gradle" version "4.0.4" 
}

task FCdeleteCollections(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.datamovement.DeleteCollectionsTask) {
………………..
  collections = ["{collection-name}"]
}
```

3. Invoke the gradle task:

```
[root@ ~] # gradle FCdeleteCollections
```

> Method Two:
> If you already scaffolded the `Project`, in my opinion, it is safer to invoke one-time deletion task like this:

```
[root@ ~] # gradle -Pdatabase={db-name} mlDeleteCollections -Pcollections={collection-name}
```

> My **preference** is to invoke such task through Java API | DMSDK.