# How to create custom REST endpoint via mlgradle?

Tags: rest, gradle, xquery, marklogic-10, ml-gradle

I want to create custom REST endpoint in MarkLogic, like "http://localhost:port/v1/resources/my_custom_endpoint"

And I am doing it via curl command in my local. But I want to integrate this with ml-gradle to automate this process as first install activity.

Please let me know how to do it via ml-gradle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093815/14419

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093815/14419), you need to put your custom REST endpoint module in your project `/src/main/ml-modules/services` directory.

You can see an example of how to configure a custom REST endpoint in the [ml-gradle sample project](https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/sample-project/src/main/ml-modules) in which it explains:

> - /services contains [custom services](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/config/resources), exposed via /v1/resources/(name of service)
>
> In addition, the rest-properties.json file in the root of this directory is used to configure the [properties of the REST API server](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/config/properties). Note that these properties are different from the configuration of the server itself - the properties are specific to the REST API out-of-the-box endpoints.